# Access a particular field in a structure within a Matlab structure

Tags: database, matlab, structure

I need to access to a structure that is inside a structure: I have a main structure called GlobalStruc that has many items (my "packets"). Each packets contains many info, i.e. has many fields. One of which is itself a structure with several fields. I need to have access to each of these fields. Any idea?

To sum up: GlobalStruc.DetailsStruc which contains many fields and has many indexes. How can I have access to these? If more convinient, can I create an array with these fields? Something like CharacteristicOfThePacket = GlobalStruc(index).DetailsStruc.FieldThatIWant

Here is an example of how the main structure was built:
`

> > GlobalStruc(1).data1 = 1;
> >     GlobalStruc(1).data2 = 12;
> >     GlobalStruc(1).moredata.velocity = 327;
> >     GlobalStruc(1).moredata.bbeta = 3.2;
> >     GlobalStruc(2).data1 = 23;
> >     GlobalStruc(2).data2 = 56;
> >     GlobalStruc(2).moredata.velocity = 442;
> >     GlobalStruc(2).moredata.bbeta = 1.7;
> >     GlobalStruc(3).data1 = 4.3;
> >     GlobalStruc(3).data2 = 7;
> >     GlobalStruc(3).moredata.velocity = 556;
> >     GlobalStruc(3).moredata.bbeta = 1.1;

`
Now I wish I could say:

```
myVelocities=GlobalStruc(:).moredata.velocity;
```

But I get this error :

```
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression,
but there were 3 results.
```

Thank you so much,

Comment: [Nested structure](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-nested-structures.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in a single line, but you can do:

```
InnerStruct = [GlobalStruc.moredata];
```

Then access the first element:

```
InnerStruct(1)

ans = 

    velocity: 327
    bbeta: 3.2000
```

or the ith element of the structure:

```
InnerStruct(i)
```

Comment: The thing is that I have many indexes in the main structure, and they share the same fields (name)... I updated my post ;) thank you for your help.

Comment: What if I need to assign the velocity of the with element to a vector A? This is actually my question ;) Thank you for your help!